# Interpolation problem on the list

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I have a List of Latitude, Longitude and Measurement.

```
a = {{{93, 104}, 290}, {{94, 103}, 292}, {{95, 105}, 291}, {{97, 109},
     294}, {{97, 102}, 295}};
```

And, I want to Interpolate this list and plot them using ContourPlot and CountryData. However, error has occured when I use Interpolation:

```
Interpolation[a]
Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All. Order will be reduced to 1.
Interpolation::umprec: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for machine numbers. The data will be coerced to machine precision.
```

The list is a just peace of my full list. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Oh sorry ContourPlot

Answer (score 1):

This is not a errors, but warnings. See code below, I hope it will be helpful.

```
f = Interpolation[a, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
ContourPlot[Quiet[Check[f[x, y], Null]], {x, 93, 97}, {y, 102, 109}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 80]
```

The main idea: draw points only inside interpolation "polygon".